# How do 'Bulk' and 'Notification' labels work in GMail?

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels

I didn't understand what do Bulk and Notification labels mean and how they work. Could you explain me which is their inteded behavior?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are Gmail smart labels, Gmail automatically categorises emails and assigns them these labels where appropriate.

The definitions of `Bulk` & `Notifications` are:

> **Bulk** mail includes any kind of mass
> mailing (such as newsletters and
> promotional email) and gets filtered
> out of your inbox by default (where
> you can easily read it later)
>
> **Notifications** are messages sent to
> you directly (like account statements
> and receipts)

Extracted from [this Google Blog Post about smart labels](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2011/03/new-in-gmail-labs-smart-labels.html)